# i need a program logic deeply machine level step by step in python .can explain anyone please

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of elements. I need to sort the values. Some example code is below, but I don't have a step-by-step understanding of the logic. Can anyone explain this clearly? I don't understand what the `if` condition is doing.

```
l=[20,3,7,12,32,14,29,43,5,8]
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[j]>l[j+1]:
            l[j],l[j+1]=l[j+1],l[j]
print(l) 

o/p: [3,5,7,8,12,14,20,29,32,43]
```

Comment: You code is only sorting the list. You could also use `l.sort()` You have to learn python basics. There are a lot of courses online.

Comment: without using built-in method , i want to do the sort values.

Comment: anyone explain this one please?

Answer (score 2):

The program is sorting the list. The "if" condition is asking, "Is the current value greater than the value to the right?" If the answer is "yes", in the next line the code swaps the values so that the left value is to the right, and the right value is to the left.

As a result, the larger values will "bubble up" to the right as the loops run. This is called "Bubble Sort" and you can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

If there is something else you are confused about, please be more specific. Right now it is not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: exact answer .but, i need more deeply explanation.

Comment: what is   l[j+1]<l[j].

Comment: It is a comparison between two variables (`l[j+1]` and `l[j]`). The comparison operator is `<` (it means "less than"). The bracket notation (`[]`) gets the values stored in a particular position within the array `l`: The j'th position or the "j+1"'th position.